# Instagram style comments, calculating width of indent based on UIButton

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, uibutton

I'm working on implementing some instagram style comments. I seem to have everything appearing correctly, except during the first load. I'm using a UIButton for the username, with a label underneath of that with the comment. The UILabel is then indented by the width of the UIButton.

It seems the problem is that the UIButton and UILabel are generated and rendered at the same time, so that they don't line up properly - on a second pass things seem to get sorted out.

**When the tableview cell is first loaded it looks like this:**

[image: When the tableview cell is first loaded it looks like this.]

**Once the tableview has scrolled away, if you scroll back it renders properly:**

[image: Once the tableview has scrolled away, if you scroll back it renders properly.]

The cellForRowAtIndexPath looks like this:

```
cell.usernameButton.setTitle(comment.user.userName, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        var style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        style.firstLineHeadIndent = cell.usernameButton.frame.width + 2
        let s = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style]

        cell.commentLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: comment.text, attributes: s)
```

The UITableViewCell just has the two components, a UIButton and UILabel with the UIButton being on top.

My question is this: ***Is there a way to tell the UILabel to render AFTER the UIButton has its autolayout computed?***

Comment: Not sure how to do so in swift, but have you tried something like `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock{ //update both UI elements in the block }];`

Comment: @LouisTur Oh wow. That worked. In swift it's NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in  }). I've never seen that before, is it common to update UI elements with the operation queue?

Comment: oh awesome that it worked @puttputt! yea, as i understand it, all of your UI updates should be made on the main queue when they are ready. mainqueue gets updated immediately, so any weird UI changes can be resolved by doing so